# Python Pandas Library get drop column and combine duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I've a data:

```
  Month  Name  Score
0 Jan   Isabel  10
1 Jan   Jane    15
2 Jan   Mark    15
3 Feb   Leo     15
4 Mar   Fabian  10
5 Mar   Hero    5
```

I need to drop names and combine duplicates:

```
  Month  Score
0 Jan     40
1 Feb     15
2 Mar     15
```

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Month'], as_index=False)['Score'].sum()`

Comment: Combining duplicates in many ways here.